# PHP: why not found class

Tags: php, class, opcode, interpretation

=== test.php ===

```
<?php

var_dump(class_exists('Base'));
var_dump(class_exists('A'));
var_dump(class_exists('B'));

class A extends Base {}
class B extends Base {}

class Base
{
    public static function e()
    {
        static $number = 0;
        $number++;
        var_dump('number is: '.$number);
    }
}
```

run it, result is:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

class A and class B extends class Base.

php found class Base.

why class A and class B not found?

Thanks.

Comment: If you var_dump after the definitions you will have all true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined a class after var_dump function. Put var_dump below into the class. then it will return true.

Comment: why class Base is can found?

Comment: It happens because of 'extends' property of Class A and Class B.
When you run this code compiler first check Class A but at that time Class Base is not defined yet so it returns false value.

Comment: Note:
Classes must be defined before they are used! If you want the class Named_Cart to extend the class Cart, you will have to define the class Cart first. If you want to create another class called Yellow_named_cart based on the class Named_Cart you have to define Named_Cart first. To make it short: the order in which the classes are defined is important.

Comment: Thanks for giving me more info!

Answer (score 2):

Classes in PHP are only bound at compile-time when the information is already available.

So, `Base` can be bound as it has no dependencies, but `A` and `B` depend on `Base`, which isn't yet bound at the time `A` and `B` are defined. So their binding is delayed to run-time. (means the class only exists after the line they're defined on has been executed).

Try putting the `Base` class before the definitions of `A` and `B` and these will be compile-time bound too.

Answer (score 1):

It's the order of the dumps, put them bellow the class code. It's advised that you first put the base class, `Base`, then afterwards declare the other classes, `A` and `B`. And only after they were made, you can actually, `var_dump` their existance.

So the code *should* look something like:

```
<?php
class Base
{
    public static function e()
    {
        static $number = 0;
        $number++;
        var_dump('number is: '.$number);
    }
}

class A extends Base {}
class B extends Base {}

var_dump(class_exists('Base'));
var_dump(class_exists('A'));
var_dump(class_exists('B'));
```

Just tested in case it's something else and it returns:

```
bool(true) bool(true) bool(true)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. But I want to know that why class Base can found, class A and class B can't found?

Comment: @bobo I'm honestly not sure, I tested the code in PHP 5.2, 5.3 and 5.4, in 5.2 for your case it returned me `true false false`, but on 5.4 it returned me `true true true`, it seams like it's related to the version of PHP (maybe there's a global class called `Base`, as well?), but only on the code that I posted above did it return `true true true` on all 3 versions.

Comment: @bobo Yep, just tested, seams like there's a global class named `Base`, when I changed the name of the class from `Base` to something unrelated (`Bazaaa` in my case) it returned false for it.

Comment: Yes! Maybe it's related to the version of PHP. I think it's also related PHP interpreter, but I don't know theory.

Comment: @NemanjaT in case you're interested about the _why_, check my answer ;-)

Comment: @bwoebi I suspected.. But thanks for verifying! Likes for you, sir/miss!